# Modeling skewed delay for combinational logic

Tags: system-verilog

I need help to model a block with different delays for various input-output paths?

```
input A;
input [3:0] B, C;
output [3:0] Y;
```

`Y = B xor C if A = 1 else Y = 0`

with `A->Y` delay of 10us when posedge A (rise delay) and 5us when negedge A(fall delay)

and `B,C - > Y` delay is 1us (applicable only if A = 1)

For my case, I might need to use procedural way and assign statements might not suit.

Comment: is it for a  synthesizable model?

Comment: @Serge No, this isn't for synthesizable model

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that worked best for me.

```
`timescale 1us/1ns

module xor_w_enabled(input A, input B, input C, output Y);
wire A_delayed;
wire B_xor_C_delayed;

assign #1 B_xor_C_delayed = B^C;
assign #(10,5) A_delayed = A;

assign Y = (A_delayed == 1) ? B_xor_C_delayed : 0;

endmodule
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: The working of the above may be seen at http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3q8b

Answer (score 0):

For non-synthesizable models you can use #delay constructs combined with `timescale to model delays. something like the following code

```
`timescale 1us/1us

module delayModule(A,B,C,Y);
   input A;
   input [3:0] B, C; // this should probably be output
   output [3:0] Y;

   reg [3:0]    tmpb, tmpy;

   always @(posedge A)
       #10us tmpb <= 1;
   always @(negedge A)
       #5us tmpb <= 0;

   always @* begin
     if (A == 1)
       #1us tmpy =(B^C);
   end
   assign B = tmpb;
   assign Y = tmpy;

endmodule // delayModule
```

Comment: I don't think having a statement like assign B = ... is legal as B is an input? Is there a typo?

Comment: @VinayakBhat Right, i think it should be `output` and probably  is the OP's typo, but it **is** legal.